# JPA and transactions in JTA mode (begin and commit)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions, jta

I have practiced **JTA** and **RESOURCE_LOCAL** modes with JPA, there is a huge difference between those two modes.

When I use **RESOURCE_LOCAL**, I have to manage transactions myself with *EntityTransaction*, and when I use **JTA** it's implicitely done by the application server.

So I would like to know when the *begin()* and *commit()* methods are executed in JTA mode.

I assume that when the application server receive a HTTP request it executes "*begin()*", and before sending an HTTP response to client it executes "*commit()*"; also, if an error happens before sending the response, it does a "*rollback()*". Am I right ?

Comment: actually, I think the transactions are delimited by default (for JTA) by the EJB method. So your servlet must call an EJB method and the transaction will start in the beginning of the EJB method and will end (or rollback) in the end of the EJB method. see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/jta/trxejb.html

Comment: This documentation looks like old, a lot of things have changed since JPA 2.0 and EJB 3.1

Comment: With JTA mode it's either done by the app server or done by yourself from UserTransaction.

Comment: Yes, I would like to know how app servers implement their UserTransaction, and if what I have said in my last paragraph is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JPA specs do not define an exact spot when `begin` and `commit` are triggered when workign with JTA transactions.

The transaction control has nothing to do with HTTP requests/responses and is not being triggered by them.

A JTA transaction will be provided for all transactional methods (all EJB methods per default) independent of their purpose.

However there are some guarantees considering JTA transactions and JPA. The transaction is guaranteed to have started when the first call to an `EntityManager` is made and is guaranteed to either commit or rollback before the method returns.

Comment: Very interesting, so it means that JTA mode is only a "_syntatic sugar_" bonus ?

Comment: Not really - the kind of transactions available is determined by the environment your application is running in. In a Servlet container like Tomcat, RESOURCE-LOCAL is all you can use, so in order to use transactions, you need to demarcate them explicitly. Sometimes this is not a trivial task. In a Java-EE compliant container, JTA transactions are a 'free bonus' for EJBs. I cannot think of a reason not to use JTA TX if you can.

Comment: I see one reason to not use JTA: If I have a DAO with CRUD methods, I may want to use one of those methods inside another (mainly create, update, and delete operations). So if a transaction ends before the method returns what could happens ? A nested transaction ? I read that JPA and JTA does not support nested transactions here : http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Transactions#Nested_Transactions . Thanks

Comment: You can invoke transactional methods inside other transactional methods and this can be done without TX nesting. The outer transaction is suspended while the inner transaction is active. Should the inner transaction fail, you can choose to either rollback the outer transaction or keep and commit it (by catching the according Exception). You cannot rollback the inner transaction from the outer one.

Comment: It would be bad if the inner transaction is a success but the outer transaction launches an exception before ending. Shouldn't the transaction for the outside method and the method called inside be the same ?

Comment: You can have a single transaction for both methods if you like, or suspend the outer transaction during the inner method or have separate transactions. This is a question of your use case. For details, see [TransactionalAttributeType](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TransactionAttributeType.html). However real nested transactions are not available. Not all databases support them anyway - Oracle for example does not.

Comment: I will try to find more documentation about JTA and TransactionalAttributeType. Thanks for all.